# Angular - How to loop over properties of an object and then loop over the values of that property

Tags: html, angular, key-value, ngfor

The following code snippet works:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items | keyvalue">
    {{item.key}} {{item.value}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

But I would like to be to nest ngFor so I could have the values in a subgraph list. What is the correct way to do this? Very new to Angular so sorry if this question has a very obvious answer.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items | keyvalue">
    {{item.key}}
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let i of item.value">{{i}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`key` to items is a string and `values` are arrays containing strings but I did not know how to declare an object with annotations like that so in the TypeScript file it is declared as any.

Comment: Can you show your sample data for `items`? Does `item.value` guarantee an array? Cause the nested *ngFor won't work if the `item.value` is not NgIterable.

Comment: ops I probably should have stated that in the problem. The keys of items are strings and the values are arrays that contain strings

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, what you want is to declare the type for the `items` instead of using `any` type.

```js
items: {
  [key: string]: string[]
}[]
```

which `{ [key: string]: string[] }` is an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) with `key` as the `string` type and value as the array of string type.

So your `items` data will be:

```
items = [
 { "a": [ "a1", "a2" ] },
 { "b": [ "b1" ] }
]
```